# Heroku app crashing when null value passed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku

I've built a web app utilizing the Instagram API. I have the below code in my 'server.js' file, the main file on my node server. The problem is, the 'text' value is often 'null' (whenever an Instagram user does not caption their image). This null value crashes my app. How would I improve this code to account for this situation?
My idea is to provide a default value for 'text' that is inserted whenever 'text' is null.

```
//Save the new object to DB
Stadium.findOneAndUpdate( {object_id: data.object_id}, { $push: {'photos':
  { img: image.data[0].images.standard_resolution.url,
    link: image.data[0].link,
    username: image.data[0].user.username,
    profile: image.data[0].user.profile_picture,
    text: image.data[0].caption.text
  }}},
  { safe: true, upsert: false },
  function(err, model) {
    console.log(err);
  }
);

//Send a socket to client with the new image
newImage({
  img: image.data[0].images.standard_resolution.url,
  link: image.data[0].link,
  username: image.data[0].user.username,
  profile: image.data[0].user.profile_picture,
  text: image.data[0].caption.text
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an unary conditional to check first if the caption even exists

```
text: image.data[0].caption ? image.data[0].caption.text : 'No caption'
```